# How to solve the truncating Shebang line in MAC OS X

Tags: python, macos, operating-system, truncate, shebang

I am trying to run a file in MAC OS X, which has the shebang line with 86 characters which looks like

```
#!/local/p4clients/pkgbuild-uGUpJ/workspace/....../runtime/bin/python2.7
```

But the OS is truncating it to only 80 characters until bin/pyt, which results in a bad interpreter, No such file or directory error.

The above path is generated one when I build and I don't have control over it to cut short.

How can I solve this problem? Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Still hurting, in 2018.  Also, be sure not to drop your card deck; getting them back in order can be a pain.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card#IBM_80-column_punched_card_format_and_character_codes